# How to do mathematical operations on the column values only if they are above certain values, otherwise set it to 1 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate 'Factor' Column by dividing 0.25 by 'Weight' Column only if value in the 'Weight' Column is above 0.25, other wise I want to set it to 1.

I have the following dataframe with 'Factor' Column as expected output:

```
                     Weight  Factor  
Date        Symbol              
1/1/2017    BTC       0.9    0.27                
            ETH       0.07   1                  
            XRP       0.03   1          
1/2/2017    BTC       0.8    0.31                
            ETH       0.07   1                   
            XRP       0.03   1
```

Here is what I have so far, but I cannot set it to 1 otherwise.

```
df['Factor'] = 0.25/df['Weight'].loc[df['Weight']>0.25]
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be an apply.

```
df['Factor'] = df['Weight'].apply(lambda weight: 0.25 / weight if weight > 0.25 else 1)
```

Apply iterates over all the rows in df['weight'] and uses each of them as input to the anonymous lambda function executing your operation.

Alternatively you could also set Factor to 1 by default and take your code.

```
df['Factor'] = 1
df['Factor'].loc[loc[df['Weight']>0.25]] = 0.25/df['Weight'].loc[df['Weight']>0.25]
```

EDIT: now with missing filter

```
df.loc[df['Weight'].notnull(), 'Factor'] = df['Weight'].loc[df['Weight'].notnull()].apply(lambda weight: 0.25 / weight if weight > 0.25 else 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. It worked perfectly for me. What if some vaues in 'Weight' column are NaNs? Is it possible to apply 'Factor' calculation only for non NaN values?

Comment: Yes just add the condition with an and statement to the if part in the lambda / .loc paet

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I have tried and df3.df3['Weight'].notnull()] and few other things but could not make it work.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Weight'].notnull(), 'Factor'] = df['Weight'].loc[df['Weight'].notnull()].apply(lambda weight: 0.25 / weight if weight > 0.25 else 1)`